# Python __init__ class is really different from constructor

Tags: python, constructor, init

I'm wondering if someone have a concrete use of `__init__` function which is not the same as a constructor.

Because I'm reading everywhere that this should not considered as a constructor, but i can't find any example taking advantage of this or really showing why it is so important.

So if someone have some concrete code showing it, i would be glad to see that !

Thank you

Comment: Where are you reading that? Because I'd consider it a constructor. It might be different from some other languages' specific notions of constructors, but that doesn't make it not a constructor any more than Python's assignment isn't assignment because it rebinds names instead of mutating values.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__()` isn't a constructor per se because `__init__()` isn't necessarily *always* called when attempting to construct an object:

```
class C(object):
  def __new__(cls):
    return 5

  def __init__(self):
    print 'I am a crow! CAW! CAW!'

c = C()
print c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Example:

     def __init__(self,value1,value2):
         self.value1 = value1
         self.value2 = value2
```

I am not an expert at python, and admit that the **init** function might have other uses, but to me it looks like, and acts like a constructor.

also by definition, its a constructor:

[Dictionary.com - Constructor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/constructor)
*scroll to bottom of link for computer related definition*

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html 
scroll down to classic classes, there it says that a class can exist without an init method, so the init initializes some stuff for the class, but at the moment the init is called, the object already exists. Or thats at least what i understand of it, since otherwise it would probably be more logical to name it `__constr__` or so, instead of `__init__`

Not really an answer to your question i guess, but you can in some cases just not use init, (if you consider "not using it" as a use for it, than i did answer part of the question?)